# Checking for random number duplicate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am generating a random number admission no and this is my DAL

```
 public static int randomgen()
   {
       int id=0;
       int number = r.Next(100);
       HttpContext.Current.Session["number"] = "SN" + (" ") + number.ToString();
       SqlConnection con = DBConnection.OpenConnection();
       try
       {
           string sql1 = "select admissionno from tblstudent_details";
           SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql1,con);
           SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           if (dr.Read())
          {
               id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);

           }
            dr.Close();
           return id;
       }

       catch (Exception)
       {

           throw;
       }
   }
```

and i am checking if there is any duplicate is getting generated but i am getting an error like Input string is not in a correct format?Where i am doing wrong?Is any better way than this?

Comment: Why are you calling `Convert.ToInt32` on an `int`?

Comment: oops i dint check that will update now....

Comment: You are saying that you are checking if there is any duplicate getting generated, but the code doesn't even make any attempt to do any checking like that. It just creates a random number and stores in a session variable, then gets another number from the database and returns it. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I am checking that in UI if exists displaying a message like generate other number if not insert is done.If not how can i check?

Comment: And `catch (Exception) { throw; }` is completely superflous.  Unless you have other code in there that does logging remove the try/catch completely.  As for the random number generating duplicates, why shouldn't it?  If it didn't, it wouldn't be random.

Comment: In what line are you getting the error, because I see an error in this line `HttpContext.Current.Session["number"] = "SN" + (" ") + number.ToString();` that should be `HttpContext.Current.Session["number"] = "SN" + " " + number.ToString();`

Comment: On another note...your SELECT statement does not have a WHERE clause so it is going to return every row in the table.  Is that what you want?

Comment: id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);

here i am getting the error.

Comment: @GeneS yes because i have to compare with every value that is present in the column.

Comment: It might be because it is a NULL check to see if object dr[0] is of type DbNull.

Comment: If you need to check every value you should use while(dr.Read()) {...}

Comment: I am thinking that dr[0] is not an integer value.  Look at the values in admissionno to see if they contain alphabetic characters.

Comment: @GeneS yes they are alphanumeric  ex:SN 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked if there is a better way...

From what I understand about the question what you are trying to do is pick a random value and then check the database to see if that value already exists.  You want to return a value back to the UI to tell the UI whether the value exists or not...

Here is a couple alternatives to consider...

```
public static bool randomgen() 
{
    bool isFound = false;
    string admissionNumber = "SN " + r.Next(100); 
    HttpContext.Current.Session["number"] = admissionNumber; 
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection()) // use "using" to guarantee connection is closed
    {
        string sql1 = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT admissionno FROM tlblstudent_details WHERE admissionno = @admissionno) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
             cmd.CommandText = sql;
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admissionno", number);
             using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 if (dr.Read())
                 {
                     isFound = (Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]) == 1)
                  }
              }
         }
     }
     return isFound;
}
```

This way you let SQL Server check to see if the value exists.

Another approach...

Not sure if you are required to prompt the user if the value is not unique, if that is not a requirement then I would consider a different approach; Keep trying until you find a unique value...Like this...

```
public static int randomgen() 
{ 
    bool isFound = true;
    while (isFound)
    {
        string admissionNumber = "SN " + r.Next(100); 
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection()) // use "using" to guarantee connection is closed
        {
            string sql1 = "SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT admissionno FROM tlblstudent_details WHERE admissionno = @admissionno) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand(sql1))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admissionno", admissionNumber);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        isFound = (Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]) == 1)
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
        return number;
    }
```

This keeps checking until a unique value is returned.  Then you return that unique value to the calling method.  Now you set HttpContent.Current session from the caller, leaving the responsibility of this method to *only* be finding a unique Admission Number.  The downside to the second approach is that it may take a long time to find a unique value, depending on how many values are already used, especially considering you are only allowing 100 values.

Hope this gives you good alternatives to consider.  Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: I am getting an error like this No overload for method 'CreateCommand' takes '1' arguments at  using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand(sql1))

in the first example

Comment: @chandra Sorry...tried to do it from memory.  Fixed the sample.